# Excluding a tag in search is hiding the watched tag panel - Can I always show it

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

I'm trying to exclude `neovim` questions from [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=-%5Bneovim%5D)

If I do a search and save that URL the watched tags panel disappears. Is there any way to always show watched tags when executing a search?

ie [https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=-%5bneovim%5d]

Looks like this
[image: Specific Search]

Whereas adding `neovim` to ignored tags looks like
[image: Ignored Tag]

I'd prefer not to see the neovim question as it's not my forte but still see the watched tags

Comment: Since this also affects all SE sites network-wide, I don't think there's a way but to request SE staff to implement/change the behavior.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT. I'd assumed it wasn't possible. I'll make a request